# Integration of Angular and JQuery.iCheck by using a directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, icheck

I'm trying to integrate [JQuery.iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) (plugin for `checkbox&Radio buttons` styling).
I followed few suggestions here that said that the way to integrate a jQuery plugins to be fully compatible with Angular `ngRepeat` is by using `directives`.

So I implemented a `directive`:

```
webApp.directive('icheck', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                var ngModelGetter, value;
                ngModelGetter = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);
                value = $parse($attrs['ngValue'])($scope);
                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-grey',
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-grey',
                    increaseArea: '20%'
                }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                        if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                            $scope.$apply(function() {
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, event.target.checked);
                            });
                        }
                        if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                            return $scope.$apply(function() {
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, value);
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This `directive` does not fully work with my `ngRepeat elements` and does not change
the properties of the `object` `vote`.

[My code - Git](https://github.com/melanker/AngICheckIntegration.git)

**My code:**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope, Votes) {
    $scope.votes  = Votes;

    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];
    $scope.selectedID = 1;
    $scope.expand = function(vote) {
        console.log("show");
        $scope.vote = vote;

        $scope.selectedID = vote.id;
    };

    $scope.change = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.votes.length; i++) {
            if($scope.votes[i].cb) {
                $scope.votes[i].status = $scope.votes.status;
                $scope.votes[i].cb = false;
            }
            $scope.show = false;
        }
    };

});

//services
webApp.factory('Votes', [function() {
    //temporary repository till integration with DB this will be translated into restful get query
    var votes = [
        {
            id: '1',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.0',
            status: 'Pending',
            userIdentification:'IP-ADDRESS'
        },
        {
            id: '111',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '4',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.1',
            status: 'Spam',
            userIdentification:'FLASH-COOKIES'

        },
        {
            id: '2',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.2',
            status: 'Approved',
            userIdentification:'HTTP-COOKIES'

        },
        {

            id: '4',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.3',
            status: 'Spam',
            userIdentification:'IP-ADDRESS'
        }
    ];
    return votes;
}]);


webApp.directive('icheck', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                var ngModelGetter, value;
                ngModelGetter = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);
                value = $parse($attrs['ngValue'])($scope);
                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-grey',
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-grey',
                    increaseArea: '20%'
                }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                        if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                            $scope.$apply(function() {
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, event.target.checked);
                            });
                        }
                        if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                            return $scope.$apply(function() {
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, value);
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="VotesCtrl">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="check" ng-click="">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" />
        </li>
        <li class="created">
            <a>CREATED</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            <b>IP ADDRESS</b>
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            <b>STATUS</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="vote in votes">
        <li class="check">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vote.cb" ng-checked="master" />
        </li>
        <li class="created" ng-class="{selected: vote.id == selectedID}">
            <a href="#" ng-click="expand(vote)">{{vote.created|date}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.status}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="details" ng-init="expand(votes[0])">
    <h3>Details:</h3>
    <div>DATE: {{vote.created | date}}</div>
    <div>IP: {{vote.ip}}</div>
    <div >
        Cookies:
        <div>
            <input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vote.userIdentification" name="iCheck" value="FLASH-COOKIES" />
            <span>FLASH COOKIES</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vote.userIdentification" name="iCheck" value="HTTP-COOKIES" />
            <span>HTTP COOKIES</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vote.userIdentification" name="iCheck" value="IP-ADDRESS" />
            <span>IP ADDRESS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Already solved on this link: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/62 by [wajatimur](https://github.com/wajatimur)

```
webApp.directive('icheck', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                var value;
                value = $attrs['value'];

                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue){
                    $(element).iCheck('update');
                })

                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-aero',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-aero'

                }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                        });
                    }
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        return $scope.$apply(function() {
                            return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Just for reference, the issue you cite has continued discussion so it's worth checking back there rather than just copy/pasting this answer.

Comment: this solved a problem I had using iCheck when upgrading an existing code base from es5 to es6

Answer (score 2):

With the code from XaReSx answer I had one issue : When updating the model from the scope the radio doesn't changed.
I had to add a timeout in the model watch :

```
$scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function (newValue) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $(element).iCheck('update');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better sololution by hackthis02

```
  .directive('icheck', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            return $timeout(function () {
                var value;
                value = $attrs['value'];

                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function (newValue) {
                    $(element).iCheck('update');
                });

                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngDisabled'], function (newValue) {
                    $(element).iCheck(newValue ? 'disable' : 'enable');
                    $(element).iCheck('update');
                })

                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'

                }).on('ifChanged', function (event) {
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                        })
                    }
                }).on('ifClicked', function (event) {
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        return $scope.$apply(function () {
                            //set up for radio buttons to be de-selectable
                            if (ngModel.$viewValue != value)
                                return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                            else
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(null);
                            ngModel.$render();
                            return
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```